# C# calling Magento soap service endpoint binding not using HTTP?

Tags: c#, api, http, endpoint

```
I am using C# to call Magento SOAP API, and we have until now using HTTP to call this service. Now we have install SSL to our website so soap is no longer available from HTTP. 

So for change I have modify service in my Visual Studio project and my App.config have change into:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Binding" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" >
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://www.ourwebstore.com/api/v2_soap/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="ServiceReference.PortType"
                name="Port" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Before modifying service request instead https was HTTP. And with HTTP works fine and fast. But when we upgrade into https, problem was, that our call services are slower, and randomly (the process is sometimes finished sometime not) I get an error (when before use of HTTP this error did not show up). Error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://www.ourwebstore.com/api/v2_soap/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
```

Any idea where is a problem?

Comment: `basicHttpBinding` is no longer relevant, since you're not using http protocol any more.  I'm assuming you had to add that to get round some problems previously, when you were using http protocol.  If that is the case then those problems would have just returned.  I don't know if it's as simple as adding an `s` to that node and calling it `basicHttpsBinding`, but a quick google search shows it's a common problem.

Comment: @Archer I have try to add basicHttpsBinding but I get error, that 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll